# How to implement bgl.glScissor with using gpu module?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, gpu-module

As you know, `bgl` module has been deprecated and will be deleted in the future Blender release.
So, I'm tackling to change my old code to use `gpu` module.

My old code uses `bgl.glScissor` to clip the target rendered by `blf` and `blf` module.
However, I could not find the way to implement same function (like `bgl.glScissor`) with `gpu` module.

Is there any way to realize `bgl.glScissor` with `gpu` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "scissor" does not appear in the docs, so I assume a direct equivalent does not exist.

What you could do instead is use a shader that discards fragments outside of the scissor rectangle. The rectangle boundaries would be passed with a uniform.

Here's the [second example](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.5/gpu.html#triangle-with-custom-shader) from the `gpu` module docs modified to do this. Added lines have been marked with a `#`.

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


vert_out = gpu.types.GPUStageInterfaceInfo("my_interface")
vert_out.smooth('VEC3', "pos")

shader_info = gpu.types.GPUShaderCreateInfo()
shader_info.push_constant('MAT4', "viewProjectionMatrix")
shader_info.push_constant('FLOAT', "brightness")
shader_info.push_constant('VEC4', "scissorRect")                 #
shader_info.vertex_in(0, 'VEC3', "position")
shader_info.vertex_out(vert_out)
shader_info.fragment_out(0, 'VEC4', "FragColor")

shader_info.vertex_source(
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "  pos = position;"
    "  gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);"
    "}"
)

shader_info.fragment_source(
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "  if ("                                                     #
    "    gl_FragCoord.x < scissorRect.x || "                     #
    "    gl_FragCoord.x > scissorRect.z || "                     #
    "    gl_FragCoord.y < scissorRect.y || "                     #
    "    gl_FragCoord.y > scissorRect.w "                        #
    "  ) discard;"                                               #
    "  FragColor = vec4(pos * brightness, 1.0);"
    "}"
)

shader = gpu.shader.create_from_info(shader_info)
del vert_out
del shader_info

coords = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0), (-2, -1, 3)]
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"position": coords})


def draw():
    matrix = bpy.context.region_data.perspective_matrix
    shader.uniform_float("viewProjectionMatrix", matrix)
    shader.uniform_float("brightness", 0.5)
    shader.uniform_float("scissorRect", [100, 100, 300, 300])    #
    batch.draw(shader)


bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')
```

[image: Triangle being clipped to the scissor rectangle as the viewport is moved]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works well for the target rendered by `gpu` module. But how do I extend this to the target rendered by `blf` module. Do I need to make a new shader?

Comment: Isn't that what `blf.clipping` does?

Comment: I overlooked `blf.clipping`, thanks!
BTW, all built-in shaders like `POLYLINE_SMOOTH_COLOR` needs to be re-written to the custom shader in this way? Or any other workarounds?

Comment: Yes. You could try using the stencil buffer I guess. There is some stencil stuff in `gpu` but I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: I could not have an idea to use the stencil buffer for built-in shaders. If possible, could you tell me your idea to use it for built-in shaders?

Comment: Btw, perhaps you're the one who requested this, but if you're not, you will want to know [an issue was just filed for adding the scissor test](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/104911).

Comment: Thanks for your information! Actually, the reporter is not me.
I have just started to implement by referring your answer, but it seems better to wait the new Python API.

Answer (score 1):

As of Blender 3.6, the gpu module now has [`gpu.state.scissor_set`](https://docs.blender.org/api/main/gpu.state.html#gpu.state.scissor_set) and [`gpu.state.scissor_test_set`](https://docs.blender.org/api/main/gpu.state.html#gpu.state.scissor_set).

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. I have also confirmed the new API has already included the latest source code.